# Specify the format of a string with letters and numbers in triggers SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers

I am actually writing a trigger with Oracle and I want to specify the format of a variable but I'm not finding the proper syntax to do that.

I have a table 'Person' which gathers students and professors and all of them have a matricule. Professors have a "pmatricule" which means a string with "p" followed by a chain of 3 to 6 numbers. Example : p456123

Students have only a matricule with 3 to 7 numbers such as : 1234567

My triggers has to compare the new matricule I want to input in my table 'Person' to check if it respects the format I described.

Has someone the syntax to do such a thing ? I have searched for a long time but my trigger is not working whatever I try.

Comment: What have you tried?  What version of Oracle are you using?  Is there a reason that you want to use a trigger rather than a more efficient constraint?

Comment: It's an exercise about triggers to learn how to understand them and how to write them with the exact syntax for a given problem. I have tried this: LIKE variable = 'p' + [0-9]{6} but the syntax is probably wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a table level CHECK constraint. You haven't provided a table description so column names are guesses.

```
alter table person add constraint person_matricule_ck check
   ( (  person_type = 'PROFESSOR' and regexp_like(matricule, '^p[0-9]{6}$') ) 
     or ( person_type = 'STUDENT' and regexp_like(matricule, '^[0-9]{7}$') )
   ) 
/
```

We shouldn't use triggers for rules which can be enforced with constraints: constraints are both idiomatic SQL and more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I shoul have precised but this is an exercise to understand how triggers work and how to write them properly. So I understand that using for this case is not relevant. But the syntax you gave seems to be the one I searched. I will try in in few hours.